# same competition ratio, but different size

Tags: estimation, inference

I am trying to give my student an advice about which application would be better to choose.

The student is preparing for the public police officer test, and there're two options.

This test is only based on the intelligence of applicant, not on the physical aspects of him.

okay,

the first option - 3000 people take the test, and only 60 would get passed.

the second option - 300 people will take the test, and only 5 would get passed.

So which one would be better choice in terms of passing the examination?

There was no more information I could have got.

score cut-line for passing the examination has always been very similar in each case.

So would it be indifferent or there might be whole different something instead?

Comment: IMO, lets say the people scores follow binomial distribution. In this situation on average you have to be better than other 98.3% of people. As we know, the more samples you take the more it looks like original (in this case binomial) distribution. So more people = you really need to be better than 98.3% of people. On the other hand when the sample is small, you get bigger error which implies that you migh not need to be so good to go to the top, as the distribution might be shiffted or have some gaps, which you might fall in. So the smaller sample = more like a lottery.

Comment: I find it inconceivable that a teacher does not evaluate a student in terms of that student's abilities, be they more physical or mental. I would go with the student's strengths, and if neither, do something else.